# Location-based game using GPS

Tags: gps, geocaching

I am not sure if this forum is proper place for that kind of question but i hope to get some advice...

I looking for some scenario (examples, ideas) for urban game (location-based game) with usage of GPS devices. The thing is that the game should touch on spatial planning subject. It will be for teenager audience.

Answer (score 10):

You might find some ideas at:

- [www.geocaching.com](http://www.geocaching.com/). Check the forums and other "Community" topics.
- [Wikipedia page for Location-based game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-based_game) which has examples.
- [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) which "is a question and answer site for professional and independent game developers".

Answer (score 6):

A fun game I've played is to do some "urban drawing". Get a map of your area and decide on the sort of thing you want to draw. Then walk the streets with your GPS, tracing out the shape of the object. Some examples can be seen [here](http://www.gpsdrawing.com/gallery.html).

You could perhaps have a list of things the kids can choose from, or do a dot-to-dot by giving them junctions to go to. They then have to decide what the object is and the best way to navigate. Or turn it into a race and have a leaderboard per object.

Answer (score 6):

One of the games/apps targeted at health improvement. Developed in cooperation with UK’s Department of Health and NHS, [**The Walk**](https://www.thewalkgame.com/):

> is designed to take three months to play through the story, a length
>   designed to be long enough for users to establish a habit of walking
>   more... The Walk uses the smartphone to passively track all day
>   movement and incorporate that into the story...

[image][image]

---

Why not help OSM grow when gaming? [**Kort Game**](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Kort_Game) is a

> Mobile Web-App to fix OpenStreetMap data.

[image]

---

Forthcoming iPhone(?) [**Map of the dead**](http://www.mapofthedead.com/game/). Quoting the website:

> Zombie apocalypse survival. Scavenge for supplies at real life
>   locations around your city, fight zombies with the weapons you find
>   and team up with your friends to complete missions together.

[image]

(via [Google Maps Mania](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.ch/2012/11/real-time-location-game-ingress.html))

---

At closed beta at the moment, but looks like good fun - [Ingress](http://www.ingress.com/) ([Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticproject.ingress)) Android game seems to to combine puzzle solving with geolocation features.

[image]

---

Fourth option: (some elements of) [**GPS drawing**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GPS_drawing) could be an [option](http://www.gpsdrawing.com/gallery.html)?

---

Also - recent article

> **Exergames for health and fitness: the roles of GPS and geosocial apps**
>   Maged N. Kamel Boulos and Stephen P. Yang *International Journal of*
>   *Health Geographics* 2013, 12:18 doi:10.1186/1476-072X-12-18

provides nice discussion of the geo-games in contex of health. [Appendix](http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/imedia/1188243289961272/supp1.pdf) provides a list of discussed apps.

Answer (score 2):

**Parallel Kingdom GPS Game**

*[image: "Parallel Kingdom is a mobile role playing and strategy game that places the virtual world on top of the real world using the GPS inside your phone. Attack, chat and interact with your friends and anyone else around you."]*

http://parallelkingdom.com/

produced by
http://www.perblue.com/Products.aspx

Available for iPhone / iPod Touch or Google Android

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be pure GPS devices, but Android phones are also ok you could have a look at TidyCity ( http://totem.fit.fraunhofer.de/tidycity/ ). It's a location based game in which you have to solve riddles, by first collecting them from an arbitrary position and then bringing them to the correct spot. You'll have to create the mission yourself though, but that shouldn't be much of a problem as there is also an easy authoring tool available from the same site.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something akin to "Capture the flag"

1) Allow the players to select playing area (in sq feet)

2) Allow players to designate teams (assign each GPS device 'red' or 'blue')

3) Split playing field in 1/2 (1 for red, 1 for blue)

4) Further subdivide the player grid into small blocks (lets say 25 on each side), and allow the player to decide which grid-square they will hide their 'flag'

5) When the game starts, normal CTF rules will be enforced, except the flag is digital, and in order to 'capture' they must enter the correct "square" of the opponent, and then return to the correct "Square" in their home base. If tagged, the flag is "Dropped" in the current square. To register a tag, determine if two opposing players are in the same "square".

For this to work, there will have to be enough "grid squares" so that a team cannot simply block an entire row or column.

Answer (score 0):

[GeoGuessr](http://geoguessr.com/) is one of the most addictive geolocation games I have played.  You get points for pinpointing a random location on earth based on Google Street view--the more precise and accurate your guess, the more points you receive.  Then challenge your friends to see if they can beat your score.

[image]

Comment: I love GeoGuessr and it is addicting but I think it is not a real geolocation game since it is not location-aware towards the user's location. I think that is what is meant with the term geolocation game.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [GPS Cops and Robbers](http://www.strabogames.com/crimwave/) type game? Uses a GPS web app and played over a wide area with multiple teams. Players can set up their own games anywhere in the world.